# Segmentation fault when trying to install packages and themes from both command line and atom user interface

Tags: atom

I newly installed **Atom** on **Ubuntu 17.10** via *Ubuntu Software*.
But I cannot install any package nor theme, neither from the user interface nor from the terminal.

Both from the *+Install Packages* pane and from the *terminal* (using `$ apm`), this is what I get:

`/snap/atom/109/usr/bin/apm: line 63: 4322 Segmentation fault (core dumped) "$binDir/$nodeBin" “cliPath" "@”`

the `4322` number is the only thing changing when I retry.

View the screenshot using the link below:

https://discourse-cdn-sjc1.com/business/uploads/github_atom/original/3X/e/7/e72adcdd430df12d0339e12ea279225415b6e28e.png

Thanks to anyone who could help me.

Comment: Not really looking in to it deeply at all - it sounds like a while loop that spawns too many async tasks (that'll get you a segfault in node) or a borked config file or filename where magic coercion of something goes wooly.

Comment: @RobotHumans I do not understand totally what you said. Is it about the config files of Atom itself? Or is it about the Ubuntu system?

Comment: I suspect it's an atom problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem comes from Ubuntu's snap.

I uninstalled Atom (which I installed using the Ubuntu software app), and installed it once more, but this time using the **Debian Package** from [the official website of atom](https://atom.io/).

Now everything works fine.